# Calculate pdf document digest

Tags: java, cryptography, itext, bouncycastle

I'm going to sign a pdf document. I 've just see an example using itext.

I've created Certificate using KeyTool. And I sign a document. PDF reader tells me that everything is all right, document is signed.

When I see a code, I notice that:

```
ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, pks, chain,null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

I do'nt undrestand one thing -  hashed PDF document is **Digest**.    function that calculates hash  of document (for example SHA 256)  t is an **DIGEST**. but in this example I have

**ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();**

**what does it mean? is it pdf document hash?...**

the full code, from itext documentation is that:

```
public static void sign(String src, String dest, PrivateKey pk,String digestAlgorithm, String provider) {

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();               
        appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(0, 10,20, 15), 1, "sig");
        ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
        ExternalSignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
        MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, signature, chain, null,null, null, 0, subfilter);


    }
```

Comment: That *digest* argument holds an object that can calculate the digest, it does not hold a pre-calculated digest value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you mkl.

answer is that : "That digest argument holds an object that can calculate the digest, it does not hold a pre-calculated digest value"